# Where are ComReleaser & WebObject ManageLiftime in ArcGIS 10.2.1

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2

I used to use ComReleaser in desktop, and WebObject in ArcGIS Server apps to release com objects - e.g. cursors and the like.

I am undertaking an upgrade from 9.3.1 to 10.2.1 of an app - and for the life of me I cannot find the ComReleaser and WebObject to help me manage com object lifetimes!

Are they just not needed anymore in 10.2.1?

Answer (score 4):

The [ComReleaser](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//004s00000023000000) class is in found in the ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Connection.Local reference. However, this cannot be added using the "Add ArcGIS Reference" dialog. You'll have to use the "Add Reference" dialog and it will be found under the .NET tab. After adding it, you'll have to manually set the Specific Version property to False.

This is how I invoke it in VB.NET

```
Using releaser As New ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.ComReleaser
    releaser.ManageLifetime(myVariable)

    'code

End Using
```

Comment: Great.  Do you know the location of the WebObject class, that does the same thing - but for ArcGIS Server?

Comment: No, I've had no experience using WebObject and there doesn't seem to be much documentation about it.